# Why doesn't .then execute after previous .then in async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Multiple calls to `_dispatch` sometimes causes the promises passed to `_dispatch` to be executed at the same time. Isn't .then supposed to execute after previous .then?

```
// Failing code
async _dispatch (promise) {
  // this._mutex is a Promise
  this._mutex = this._mutex.then(() => promise)
  return Promise.resolve(this._mutex)
}

// Possibly working code
async _dispatch (promise) {
  console.log('START_CS', promise)
  while (Atomics.load(this.done, 0) === 0) {
    await this.sleep(50)
  }
  Atomics.store(this.done, 0, 0)
  console.log('IN_CS', promise)
  const ret = await promise
  Atomics.store(this.done, 0, 1)
  console.log('END_CS', promise)
  return ret
}
```

`_dispatch` is used in the following manner:

```
async getStatus (ports) {
  const request = // ...
  return this._dispatch(someAsyncFunctionReturningArray(request, ports))
}
const polling = () => {
  const sleep = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
  const status = this.getStatus().then(() => {}).catch(() => {})
  return Promise.all([sleep, status])
    .then(polling)
}
polling()
```

polling() and another similar block of code is running at the same time. I noticed that `someAsyncFunctionReturningArray` is called concurrently.

Comment: Promises don’t get executed. Maybe you’re trying to achieve something like `_dispatch(action)` with `this._mutex.then(() => action())`?

Comment: I've added more details to the question.

Comment: Are you trying to assign `promise` to `this._mutex`? Or simply await `promise` and then proceed?

Comment: I want the promise that was passed into `_dispatch` to be resolved before promises in subsequent calls to `_dispatch` are executed.

Comment: As soon as you call `someAsyncFunctionReturningArray(request, ports)`, the associated actions are taken. That function doesn’t care about what you do with the promise it returns and doesn’t wait to find out.

Comment: Does `_mutex` do any asynchronous I/O?

Comment: (Also, do you actually need to use `Atomics`? If you aren’t sharing a buffer across multiple threads with worker_threads, you don’t.)

Comment: What is the purpose of `Math.random()` passed to `._dispatch()`? Does `someAsyncFunctionReturningArray(request, ports)` return a `Promise`?

Comment: @Ry- `someAsyncFunctionReturningArray` is async, so doesn't it return a `Promise` that is executed later?

Comment: What is the purpose of `this._mutex`?

Comment: @Quentc: The promise isn’t a task – it’s just information about the state of the task. By the time you get a promise, the task has already started. The promise is what allows you to act on the task’s completion.

Comment: if you pass a promise to `_dispatch` then delaying some execution is already out the window. The function that created that promise has already been called. the only thing that your code does is ensure that the responses are returned in the same order as the promises have been passed to `_dispatch()`

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry it was left over from some debugging statements.

Comment: @Quentc Then the only requirement is to await `promise`? Or, is the issue the second block of code? Should `promise` be assigned to `this._mutex`?

Comment: @Ry- Thanks, replacing promise with a function that returns a promise fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises carry information about the state of a task and allow you to act on that state. They don’t, in general, represent tasks themselves. Here’s the equivalent of what you’re doing:

```
async function foo() {
    console.log('foo() task ran');
}

function delay() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
}

const promise = foo();

delay().then(() => promise)
```

This isn’t going to delay `promise` by a second, because `promise` is just an object that can say “resolved with value X”, “rejected with error Y”, or “pending”. There’s no concept of delaying promises – you delay *tasks*. The work is done by `foo` and starts when you call `foo()`.

It’s not quite clear what the correct replacement would be in your question. I think this is what you were going for:

```
_dispatch (action) {
  this._mutex = this._mutex.then(() => action())
  return this._mutex
}
```

```
async getStatus (ports) {
  const request = // ...
  return this._dispatch(() => someAsyncFunctionReturningArray(request, ports))
}
```

but it’s possible there’s an entirely different approach that works better, and we’d need more details on what you’re trying to accomplish with this queue to recommend one.

Comment: Opening sentence, "Promises carry information about the state of a task and allow you to act on that state" doesn't make for the best intro to Promises, IMO. If I was starting out, I'm not sure I would learn a lot from it. For me, the statement "A promise represents the eventual result of an asynchronous operation" from the [Promise] TagWiki entry is a much better starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A Promise is not a task that generates a value, it is rather a value immeadiately returned by tasks that take a while, to then somewhen pass out the result. Adding a promise to another promise through chaining them does not influence what the tasks are doing. However a callback could be called when a promise resolves, like:

```
async _dispatch(callback) {
 this._mutex = this._mutex.then(() => callback());
 return this._mutex;
}
```

That can then be used as:

```
 const getStatus = (ports) => this.dispatch(() => {
   const request = // ...
   return someAsyncFunctionReturningArray(request, ports);
 });

const sleep = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))

const polling = () => {
  const status = this.getStatus().then(() => {}).catch(() => {})
  return Promise.all([sleep, status])
   .then(polling)
};

polling();
```